# Real-Time Como funciona. Pois estou com problemas no meus testes Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, websocket, realtime-database

O que eu preciso? Preciso que quando um usuario no frontend mande uma mensagem para o sistema e o sistema (dashboard backend) receba uma notificação em tempo real que é a mensagem acabou de ser criado.
Estou fazendo assim. No meu controller no método store() do controller responsável pelo Model Contato, ele grava no banco de dados o contato do formulário do frontend chamando o evento NotificacaoContato
Ficando assim:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  //dados do formulário contato 
  $result = Contato::create($request->all());
   //Evento a ser chamado
  \Event::fire(new NotificacaoContato($result)); 
}
```

Agora eu não sei bem como registrar esse evento no AppServiceProvider
Como eu faria isso?
Continuando.
No meu .env configuro as variáveis de ambiente da seguinte forma:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID="Meu ID"
PUSHER_APP_KEY="Minha chave que eu peguei la no site do push.com "
PUSHER_APP_SECRET="Chave secreta pega no push.com"
```

Depois eu descomentei no meu array Provider que fica em App\config\app.php
Justamente esse a 2 linha no meu caso

```
 Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

Logo depois No meu Evento em si eu fiz dessa forma:

```
class NotificacaoContato implements ShouldBroadcast
 {
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $contato;
public function __construct($contato)
{
    $this->contato = $contato;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('notificacao-contato');
}
}
```

Agora no minha View eu coloquei importei o  do push para o meu template dashboard backend juntamente com o script que o push ja disponibiliza. Ficando assim:
View (Template dashboard backend)

```
// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('aqui vai a minha chave o mesmo do .env', {
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('notificacao-contato');
channel.bind('App\\Event\\NotificacaoContato', function(data) {
    alert('Uma Conatato foi enviado');
});
</script>
```

O que acontece com esse código. Quando eu mando eu submeto o formulário para o método store() no site do push.com mostra que algo acontece. Que o meu evento e chamado. Mais pera ai, não era para aparecer o alert no meu dashboard backend?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saida no console
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem. Vou mostrar aqui como resolvi esse problema que eu estava tendo. Só que em vez de fazer a notificação do frontend para o Backend, eu fiz ao contrários, do Backend para o frontend. Logo mudei o conceito que eu estava querendo fazer, mais o conceito é o mesmo. Então a ideia agora é, quando eu criar um artigo que o no frontend seja notificado que acabou de chegar um novo artigo.

O que eu mudei foi em algumas partes. 
No meu meu Evento chamado NotificacaoContato eu mudei para NotificacaorArtigo já que eu quero notificar um novo artigo então o nome faz sentido.
E nesse Evento NotificacaorArtigo tirei a privação do canal e deixei ele como se fosse publico Dessa forma:
Como estava antes:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
 return new PrivateChannel('notificacao-contato');
}
```

Veja que ele esta como PrivateChannel. Então mudei para:

```
return new Channel('notifica-artigo');
```

assim eu tive acesso no frontend.

Como eu estava com dúvidas sobre se eu registrava o eventos no AppServiceProvider ou registrar em qualquer outro lugar, não precisou. Por que eu estou chamando o evento diretamente.
Já no meu frontend eu criei uma div colocando o css para deixar como display : none. Ficando assim:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 alert alert-success artigo" id="msg" style="display: none"></div>
```

```
<script>

// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = false;

var pusher = new Pusher('Aqui vai a minha chave', {
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifica-artigo');
channel.bind('App\\Events\\NotificacaoArtigo', function(data) {
   //aqui add o texto na div
   $('.artigo').text('O artigo (' + data.artigo.titulo + ') acaba de ser criado');
    //aqui eu mostro a div que esta escondida pelo display:none 
    $('.artigo').show();
    //aqui eu escondo a div depois de alguns segundos. 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#msg').fadeOut(15000);
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```

Então dessa forma ficou bem bacana é justamente o que eu estava precisando. Muito grato para os que me ajudaram a ter um norte. Vendo o que eu fiz vou fazer depois o reverso. recebendo uma notificação na área administrativa vinda de um formulário do frontend como eu propus fazer na minha ideia original do post.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade a ideia do serviço de Real-Time é o exatamente o contrário.

O serviço de broadcast do Laravel possibilita a sua aplicação a realizar requisições do lado do servidor para o lado do cliente através do uso de serviços que implementem web sockets, como o Pusher neste caso.

1) Não é necessário registrar o provider **BroadcastServiceProvider** e sim o EventServiceProvider.

2) O arquivo config/broadcasting.php deve estar criado com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        ],
    ],
];
?>
```

3) A action que dispara o evento para o serviço deve instanciar um objeto Pusher e realizar a chamada do método trigger.

Por exemplo:

```
$options = [
    'cluster' => 'us2',
    'encrypted' => true
];

$pusher = new Pusher(
    'xxx',
    'yyy',
    'zzz',
    $options
);

$pusher->trigger('notificacao-contato', 'Nome_Para_o_Evento', ['msg' => ':)']);
```

4) No Front-End tu deves realizar o bind do teu cliente no canal criado e explicitar o nome do evento (disparado na trigger dentro da tua action) que o serviço ficará escutando.

Exemplo:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('xxxx', {
    cluster: 'us2',
    namespace: false,
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('notificacao-contato');

channel.bind("Nome_Para_o_Evento", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Espero que ajude!

Abraços.

Comment: Hum. Entendi. Mais deixa eu fazer mais algumas perguntas Lorenzo. No num. 3) que action e essa que vc esta falando onde fica esse arquivo?
$options = [
    'cluster' => 'us2',
    'encrypted' => true
];

$pusher = new Pusher(
    'xxx',
    'yyy',
    'zzz',
    $options
);
Isso e no meu controller ? Essa parte eu me perdi. E o que seria esse yyy zzz xxx ?

Comment: Lorenzo, entendi que o @NatanMelo chama de "dashboard backend" é uma área administrativa da própria aplicação. Portanto não seria ao contrário como você disse. A necessidade continua sendo o servidor enviar uma mensagem para o front-end (administrativo). Natan, por favor confirma se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Justamente. Quando um usuario da internet enviar no formulário de contato para a área administrativa que eu receba la na área administrativa uma notificação. Do front end do usuário -> para área aministratriva (Backend dashboard) . @bfavaretto

Comment: Editei o post e estou mostrando a saída que esta dando. Mais na minha view continua não aparecendo nada. Agora eu fiz assim Quando eu publicar uma artigo na minha view principal aparece um alerta ou o que seja dizendo que foi postada um novo artigo @bfavaretto

Comment: Caramba Resolvi esse po** putz que coisa complicada para eu botar para funcionar. Mais estou muito feliz.

Comment: @bfavaretto Entendi então. Mas estava me referindo a teoria mesmo quando quis dizer que era o contrário. Era só pra explicitar que a ideia de utilizar um serviço que utilize web sockets é permitir que o servidor tenha "autonomia" de se comunicar com o cliente sem que haja uma requisição por parte do cliente (como é o padrão das arquiteturas web). :)

Comment: Arthur, que bom que conseguiu. Mas respondendo a tua pergunta anterior. A action a qual eu me referia era o teu método que receberia a requisição, tua Controller. E os "xxx", "yyy" e "zzz" eram apenas para representar que ali deveriam estar tuas credenciais  abraço!